# Why Spark BlockMatrix implementation is not strictly increasing time duration curve?

Tags: apache-spark, matrix-multiplication

I have created some matrices with different sizes and save each matrix in a separate file in csv format with the format as

```
row,column,value.
```

The code for generating matrices is as follows

```
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
  Integer next = rng.nextInt(5) + 1;
  bw1.write(i + "," + j + "," + next);
 }
}
```

Now, when I tested matrices with increasing cardinality I got some weird results. Sometimes, instead of increasing time duration, it takes less time when I increase the size of the matrices. The results are as follows

```
(8192x8192)x(8192x8192) --- 254 sec.
(8193x8194)x(8194x8193) --- 190 sec.
(16382x16383)x(16383x16382) --- 1110 sec.
(16384x16384)x(16384x16384) --- 1619 sec.
(16385x16386)x(16386x16385) --- 1038 sec.
```

I have checked the source code, but failed to identify the reason.

Can anyone tell me why is it behaving like this?

Thanks in advance